# Distributed Erlang and the CAP theorem

Tags: erlang, distributed-system

By the [CAP theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem), it is impossible for a [distributed Erlang system](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html) to simultaneously provide all three of the following guarantees:

- Consistency (all Erlang runtimes, or nodes, see the same data at the same time)
- Availability (node failures do not prevent survivors from continuing to operate)
- Partition Tolerance (the system continues to operate despite arbitrary message loss)

A distributed Erlang system can support *zero*, *one*, or *two* of the guarantees.

Using Erlang and OTP, how can each guarantee be implemented? Most distributed Erlang applications make the practical choice for higher levels of  A and P, and settle for "eventual consistency". It seems Erlang itself was designed to support distributed (P), fault-tolerant (A), soft-real-time, non-stop applications.

**The programming language (Erlang), run-time system (ERTS), and set of libraries (OTP) are designed for building distributed fault-tolerant applications; how do I do the three things that *define* distributed fault-tolerant applications?**

Comment: Your updated question, is like saying: "I have a hammer. How can I build a house, a school, or a boarding school?"  The best answers you are going to get will explain CAP theory, but the implementation details are far to complicated to give a simple set of instructions.

Comment: I get your point, but I thought it was more like saying: "I have a programming language, runtime system, and lots of libraries (Erlang/OTP) designed for building distributed fault-tolerant applications. How can I do the three things that _define_ distributed fault-tolerant applications?"

Comment: I dont see this Consistency bullet in Erlang.. Just to mention mnesia and its problems due to network latency. Many times I see a cluseter build over FSMs which are in random states.. Partition T. - the same. Try to merge state or mnesia (splited tables), it usually is done by choosing a master and dumping the other half after a joining nodes. Vector clocks would be easy to implement. I did it recently, but in tests with real data they exploded before merging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A really good example I found is [Riak](https://wiki.basho.com/display/RIAK/Riak), a distributed key-value store based on Amazon's Dynamo and built using Erlang and OTP. The [tunable CAP controls](https://wiki.basho.com/display/RIAK/Tunable+CAP+Controls+in+Riak) let you dynamically "choose" your levels of consistency and availability; it chooses to focus on the A and P of CAP, which makes it eventually consistent. Riak is open-source, and there are a number of good articles online regarding its implementation.

Another good example is [Dynomite](http://github.com/cliffmoon/dynomite), PowerSet's Dynamo-clone-in-Erlang. Although the project has been dead for a while, it serves as a useful functional design document on how to build a Dynamo clone.

These two projects are themselves based on Amazon's [Dynamo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo_%28storage_system%29), an incrementally scalable, highly-available key-value storage system. The technology is designed to give its users the ability to trade-off cost, consistency, durability and performance, while maintaining high-availability. The paper is a good read.

Answer (score 5):

**EDITED for clarity**

It depends on the design of your application and not the platform in which you implement it.  You could implement any 2 of the guarantees, with just about any language or platform combination.

Comment: Erlang is both the programming language and the runtime system. A distributed Erlang system consists of a number of Erlang runtime systems communicating with each other. Your answer isn't helpful at all; I could write a distributed system that supports two of the guarantees in any Turing tarpit.

Comment: @Rudiger, maybe a better answer would have been it is application dependent, will make more clear.

Comment: +1 CAP Theorem has nothing with the programming language to do. And Rudiger linked to the answer, you can not have them all at the same time. It's up to the developer to choose any two for the application.

Comment: I edited my question to better reflect what I was trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Erlangs strength should be with chosing A&P, but as with any system it is possible to chose any two or less. This is partly due to erlangs programming model with all communication through message passing. If you use good Erlang style you don't use shared memory to communicate between processes.

Answer (score -1):

I think this theorem should be considered in only one layer. What is a layer? It is something like OSI-ISO layers but for databases: application/db, OS, disk/hardware. All of the CAP conditions cannot be satisfied in one layer. Erlang/OTP operates in application layer so cover 2 of them with Erlang (you can choose, because of flexibility of Erlang) and the last one cover with OS (i.e. file system) or hardware layer (raid).

Comment: why? I come up with this explanation as acceptable for new people in scalable software. The point is: pick two. No matter if it is Erlang/OTP or any other environment it is going to be always two. I like to think about it like dimensions and you can cover only 2 out of three. Riak claims to be tunable per request, but it is not. To get C, you need to have N = no_of_machines, so you do not have P. Regularly N=something so we have P but no C. A here is granted. There are always trade offs. For me CAP is like set of requirements, but the thing is, there is no product which needs C&A&P.